# jQuery BlockUI Plugin - How to set a callback function when Unblock occur

Tags: jquery

i am using jquery BlockUI Plugin. i looking for a way to have callback function should call when after unblock.

here is my code

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "UPSLabelFormUS.aspx/ProcessInfo",
    data: JSON.stringify(DTO),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
        if (data.d[0].Message == "SUCCESS") {
            var _images = [data.d[0].LabelImagePath];
            $.each(_images, function (e) {
                $(new Image()).load(function () {
                    ImgPath = data.d[0].LabelImagePath;
                    _TrackNumber = data.d[0].TrackNumber;
                    $('#imgHolder').html("<img src='" + data.d[0].LabelImagePath + "' width='330' height='498' border='0'  />").fadeIn().show('slow');
                    $("#Print").show();
                    $("#Fax").show();
                    $('div#content').unblock();

                }).attr('src', this);
            });
        }
        else {
            $('div#content').unblock();
            alert(data.d[0].Message);
        }
    }
                ,
    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        $('div#content').unblock();
        alert(textStatus);
    }
});
```

here i need to have notification.

```
else {
            $('div#content').unblock();
            alert(data.d[0].Message);
        }
```

after unblock i need notification by callback so tell me the way to have callback functionality with unblock. thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can specify callback method like this:

```
$('div#content').unblock({
    onUnblock: function() { alert(data.d[0].Message); }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can place the code inside a function and pass the callback to it like this:

```
function someNmae (fn){
    ...
    else {
        $('div#content').unblock();
        alert(data.d[0].Message();

        // Execute Callback Function//
        if (typeof fn == 'function') {
            fn.call(this);
        }
    }
    ....
}

// Run Function w/ Callback //
someName(function(){
    // Callback Code Here //
});
```

EDIT:

According to the [documentation](http://jquery.malsup.com/block/#options) there is a setting called onUnblock where you can pass a standard function to run on each unblock like this:

```
$.blockUI({
    onUnblock : function(){
        // Callback Function Here //
    }
});
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: please make me understand how this works....function someNmae (fn){
    ...
    else {
        $('div#content').unblock();
        alert(data.d[0].Message();

        // Execute Callback Function//
        if (typeof fn == 'function') {
            fn.call(this);
        }
    }
    ....
}

// Run Function w/ Callback //
someName(function(){
    // Callback Code Here //
});